# Suppose that a bowl contains 100 chips: 30 are labelled 1, 20 are labelled 2, and 50 are labelled 3.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The chips are thoroughly mixed, a chip is drawn, and let $X$ be the number on the chip.

1) Compute $P(X = x)$ for every real number $x$.

2) Suppose the first chip is replaced, a second chip is drawn, and let $Y$ be the number on the second chip. Compute $P(Y = y)$ for every real number $y$.

3) Let $W = X + Y$ and compute $P(W = w)$ for every real number $w$.

---

I have the solution for this:

I understand part 1 and 2, but not 3.

We define $W = X+Y$, and so this means that $W(w)=X(w)+Y(w), \forall w\in\mathbb{R^1}$

First my question is, why do we not consider $W(1)$? We have defined $X(1)$ and $Y(1)$, so why not $W(1)$?

Secondly, and probably the most important question is, how do they get $W(2)=0.12$? From the equation $W(2)=X(2)+Y(2)=0.2+0.2 = 0.4$. But they don't follow the equation. Why?

There's two questions I'm asking here.

[image]

Comment: You get $W=2$ if $X=1$ and $Y=1.$ Since the chips are replaced it is $P(W=2)=P(X=1)P(Y=1).$

Comment: But we have just defined $W$ as the sum of those two. $w=2$ so how are you getting $x=1,y=1$?

Comment: If the sum of the labells is $2$ the only possibility is $1+1.$ In case the sum is $4$ you have to consider $1+3,2+2$ and $3+1.$

Comment: Okay, I understand what you are saying. Then why is the definition of saying $W=X+Y$ means $W(w)=X(w)+Y(w)$ incorrect? Clearly we can't just sub in $w=2$ for both $X/Y$ as this would be wrong

Comment: What is $W(3)?$ Do you mean $W=3?$ In such a case it is $W=3$ iff $X=1,Y=2$ or $X=2, Y=1.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are five possibilities for the sum of the numbers on the two chips: $$ X+Y \in \{2,3,4,5,6\}$$

---

- If $X+Y=2$, then $(X,Y)$ must be $(1,1)$.
- If $X+Y=3$, then $(X,Y)$ can be $(1,2)$ or $(2,1)$.
- If $X+Y=4$, then $(X,Y)$ can be $(1,3)$, $(2,2)$, or $(3,1)$.
- If $X+Y=5$, then $(X,Y)$ can be $(2,3)$ or $(3,2)$.
- If $X+Y=6$, then $(X,Y)$ must be $(3,3)$.

---

The probability that $X+Y=2$ is the same as the probability that both $X=1$ and $Y=1$. Since the chip is replaced, $X=1$ and $Y=1$ are independent events, so we simply multiply their probabilities to find the probability that both occur:

$$P(X+Y=2) = P(X=1)P(Y=1) = 0.3^2 = 0.09$$

The probability that $X+Y=3$ is the same as the probability that both $X=1$ and $Y=2$, plus the probability that both $X=2$ and $Y=1$:

$$P(X+Y=3) = P(X=1)P(Y=2) + P(X=2)P(Y=1)= 0.3\cdot 0.2 \cdot 2= 0.12$$

---

The same reasoning applies for the other three cases, and we get the final answers of $0.09, 0.12, 0.34, 0.2$, and $0.25$.

As an extra check, when you finish a problem like this, make sure that all of the probabilities add up to $1$ (since there are no other possibilities for the value of $X+Y$, this should be the case:

$$0.09 + 0.12 + 0.34 + 0.2 + 0.25 = 1$$

Answer (score 1):

$W = X + Y$ is a random variable that is computed as
$P(W=w) = \Sigma_{x=1}^3 P(X=x)\times P(Y=w-x) $

Hence, it should now be clear that $P(W=1) = P(X=1)\times P(Y=0)$. Since $P(Y=0)=0, P(W=1)=0$

Similarly other values can be calculated.
eg $$P(W=3) = P(X=1)\times P(Y=2) + P(X=2)\times P(X=1)$$ which gives the required answer.